# Amazon.Transfer.Model.InvalidRequestException: Cannot set HomeDirectory for LOGICAL HomeDirectoryType

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-3.1, aws-sftp

Friends,

I have a `Dictionary<int, string>` which contains a list of DepartmentIds and its s3 folder names. For e.g., `{ {key=1, value="dept-1"}, {key=2, value="dept-2"} }` etc.
For each of those s3 folders, I would like to create a user `user-dept-group-{DepartmentId}` mapped logically to its SFTP server folder. For e.g., `user-dept-group-1` will have a logical folder `dept-1` mapped to `my-s3-bucket/dept-1` in the aws sftp server. Below is the code I was using and I am always getting `Cannot set HomeDirectory for LOGICAL HomeDirectoryType` error.

If I comment the `HomeDirectoryMappings` and set the `HomeDirectoryType` to `HomeDirectoryType.PATH`, then I see the user getting created.

```
public async Task<List<CreateUserResponse>> SetupSftpUser(Dictionary<int, string> masterDeptFolders)
{
    var result = new List<CreateUserResponse>();
    var awsTransferClient = new AmazonTransferClient(AwsAccessKey, AwsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    foreach (var (key, folder) in masterDeptFolders)
    {
    var createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest
    {
        HomeDirectory = $"/{ParentBucketName}/{folder}/",
        HomeDirectoryMappings = new List<HomeDirectoryMapEntry>{new HomeDirectoryMapEntry{Entry = $"/{folder}", Target = $"/{ParentBucketName}/{folder}" } },
        HomeDirectoryType = HomeDirectoryType.LOGICAL,
        // Policy = GetSftpPolicy(),
        Tags = GetTags(key, folder),
        ServerId = SftpServerId,
        UserName = $"user-dept-group-{key}",
        Role = SftpRole,
        //SshPublicKeyBody = "MY_DEPT_SSH.PUB_FILE"
    };

    var response = await awsTransferClient.CreateUserAsync(createUserRequest);
    if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        result.Add(response);
    }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:** One thing I noticed in all the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/transfer/create-user.html) is the s3 bucket folder names are mentioned as `<s3bucket>/home/username`. Should I need to have this folder structure to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `HomeDirectory` was not needed and the Entry value must be set to `\`. Below is how the `createUserRequest` look like.

```
var createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest
{
    HomeDirectoryMappings = new List<HomeDirectoryMapEntry>{new HomeDirectoryMapEntry{Entry = "/", Target = $"/{ParentBucketName}/{folder}" } },
    HomeDirectoryType = HomeDirectoryType.LOGICAL,
    // Policy = GetSftpPolicy(),
    Tags = GetTags(key, folder),
    ServerId = SftpServerId,
    UserName = $"user-dept-group-{key}",
    Role = SftpRole,
    //SshPublicKeyBody = "MY_DEPT_SSH.PUB_FILE"
};
```